# USB WiFi Adapter Disconnects Every Few Minutes

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, desktop

My new Windows 10 desktop does not have a built in WiFi Adapter card, so I have been attempting to use a USB WiFi adapter that worked well for my Raspberry Pi devices.

When I plug in the USB WiFi adapter (EDIMAX 150Mbps Wireless 802.11bgn Nano USB Adapter) to my desktop, it will connect to a WiFi network for around 5 minutes before having no connectivity. The network I was connected to is still visible; however, no other networks show up. I have attempted to update drivers, reinstall the USB device, and turn off the power management options but the issue persists.

It is not an issue of the router as I have my Xbox right next to it running perfectly.

To fix the issue once it goes down, I simply run the network troubleshooter and it says it has "reset the WiFi Adapter" and in the more in-depth description that it reset the default gateway. However, the problem once again persists about 5 minutes later.

In the wlan report, each issue disconnect ends with:

```
WLAN AutoConfig service has successfully disconnected from a wireless network.
```

And the disconnect reason either:

```
The network is disconnected by the driver.
```

or

```
The network is disconnected due to a policy disabling auto connect on this interface.
```

EDIT: I updated and reinstalled all my chipset drivers and it fixed the issue for about an hour before a desktop hibernation made the issue begin once again.

Answer (score 1):

After much research, many attempts at updating drivers and changing settings, I decided to simply buy a higher quality WiFi adapter, which is working much better. However, after reinstalling my chipset drivers as mentioned in the EDIT, the old adapter worked for much longer. A combination of updated chipset drivers and a better adapter have fixed my problems.

Thank you for anyone who looked at my question and attempted to help.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question, and kudos for solving this.  Don't forget to accept your own answer to indicate that the problem has been solved (you can do that 2 days after posting the question).