# USB Wifi adapter disconnects every few minutes from home network - but can still connect to other networks

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, wifi-configuration

I have a TP-Link USB Wifi Adapter that disconnects about 5 to 6 times a day.
Initially I thought this was a problem with the device itself because when I unplug it then plug it back in, it reconnects to the network for a while.

My most recent discovery is that whilst it disconnects from my home network, it still shows other networks around us.
So I did a test: Setup a hotspot on my phone and connected to it, which worked, but it still wouldn't connect to my home network.
I've also checked a number of other devices and they're still connected to my home network when this happens, and none of them drop off when I do.

I've tried disabling all the power settings for the device too.

I've even got another Netgear Wifi adapter that I'm trying and it does the exact same thing.
So two adapters doing the same thing, can't connect to the home network when all other devices can, but can connect to another wireless network??

PS. The Netgear adapter has a USB extension cord which I use for both devices. But the same thing happens if I plug them directly into the PC.

**Similar Questions:**
[USB WiFi Adapter Disconnects Every Few Minutes](https://superuser.com/questions/1467323/usb-wifi-adapter-disconnects-every-few-minutes)
However in the above mentioned case, no other networks show up. On mine they do.

[Wireless disconnects every 30 minutes](https://superuser.com/questions/111561/wireless-disconnects-every-30-minutes)
This had to do with the router, but other devices on my network on not doing the same thing.

EDIT:
This has progressively gotten worse. It now happens 2-3 times per Hour.

Comment: Model of your router? Model of the adapter?

Comment: @Appleoddity it's a Tenda F9 - https://www.tendacn.com/za/product/f9.html. I also have a TP Link Deco P9 hybrid mesh system setup, but this was happening before I installed that. In fact I installed the Deco system because I thought range was part of the problem